# Saving Elman Network weights

Tags: neural-network

I have developed a time-series prediction engine based on an implementation of an Elman Network. Everything works fine when I use it synchronously (that is, presenting the samples to the input layer, do the training, then read the predictions directly from output neurons). However, when I save the network (weights and biases) at the end of a training session in order to decouple the training and running phases, what should I do with the context neuron values? Should I save them from the last epoch/sample, or should I re-initialize them to 0 before presenting a new Sample to obtain a prediction? I have actually tried both, but I never get to see the same results as in the synchrounous approach.

Comment: What framework are you using? Can you post your code?

Comment: I am not using any framework. I wrote the prediction engine from scratch. Mine is a conceptual question, related to recurring neural networks. Basically,  once a network is trained and weights are somehow saved, how should context neurons be handled when presenting a new sample (one that was not part of the training phase) to the input layer?